# 1st Steps in Beat Tracking (ios)

Tags: ios, beat-detection

I'm using the method Eric D. Scheirer describes in the article "Tempo and beat analysis of acoustic musical signals" to determine the tempo of a song (beat tracking), but I have no idea what the first step is.

I've looked into libraries like aubio and coreplot to help me determine this 1st step, yet I'm still a little bit confused as to where to start.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is very broad and not a great fit for a Q&A site like SO. You should either rephrase your question to be more specific (like specifying what you don't understand about the above article and libraries), or ask a different question, perhaps after you've implemented something which is giving you trouble.

Comment: I've figured out what I would like to do as far as the idea that I've had and this question is no longer relevant. Thanks for the help, however!

Comment: if you have any success on this you might share your experience.